# On an application of Ito's lemma

Tags: volatility, returns, martingale, itos-lemma

Assume that instantaneous returns are generated by the continuous time martingale:

$$dp_t = \sigma_t dW_t$$

where $W_t$ denotes a standard Weiner process and One day returns are denoted by $r_{t+1} = p_{t+1} - p_t$. Then By Ito's lemma  we have:

$$E_t (r_{t+1}^2) = E_t \Bigg( \int_0^1 r_{t + \tau}^2 d \tau \Bigg) = E_t \Bigg( \int_0^1 \sigma_{t + \tau}^2 d \tau \Bigg) =  \int_0^1 E_{t} \Bigg( \sigma_{t + \tau}^2  \Bigg) d \tau  $$

where $E_t$ denotes conditional expectation at time t.

I am very rusty with Ito's lemma applications and do not seem to recall where the $d \tau$ comes up from. Would anybody mind explaining these 3 equalities?

Comment: This is basically Ito's isometry.

Comment: @Gordon that is the first equality, right?

Comment: That is correct. But the notation here is bit sloppy, the square $r^2_{t+\tau}$ within the first integral should be the quadratic variation. But in many book, such as that of John Hull, this sloppy notion is used.

Comment: Thanks could you even tell me why we can exchange $r_{t+\tau}^2$ with $\sigma_{t+\tau}^2$ in the second equality? I know it is a popular approximation but why can we keep equality in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Ito's isometry,
\begin{align*}
E_t (r^2_{t+1}) &= E_t \bigg(\int_t^{t+1} \sigma_s dW_s \int_t^{t+1} \sigma_s dW_s\bigg)\\
&= E_t \bigg(\int_t^{t+1} \sigma_{\tau}^2 \,d\tau\bigg) \\
&= E_t\bigg(\int_0^1 \sigma_{\tau+t}^2 \,d\tau\bigg) \\
&=\int_0^1 E_t\big(\sigma_{\tau+t}^2\big) \,d\tau.
\end{align*}
The identity
\begin{align*}
E_t (r^2_{t+1}) &= E_t\bigg(\int_0^1 r_{\tau+t}^2 \,d\tau\bigg)
\end{align*}
is sloppy. It is better to write as
\begin{align*}
E_t (r^2_{t+1}) &= E_t\bigg(\int_0^1 d\langle r_{\tau+t}, r_{\tau+t}\rangle\bigg),
\end{align*}
where $\langle r_{\tau+t}, r_{\tau+t}\rangle$ is the quadratic variation.

Comment: Thanks now I understand the notation issue you where talking about.